# How to save html renderings with carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave (:fog with s3). I wanna upload a rails rendered HTML Text, to S3. So far so good it works:

```
class Post
  attr_accessible :snippet
  mount_uploader :snippet, HtmlSnippetUploder
end

class PostController

  def render_snippet
      # logic for rendering a snippet
  end

  def render_and_upload_snippet
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    data = render_to_string(:render_snippet)
    file = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "tmp", 'test.html'), 'w') { |f| f << data}
    @post.snippet.store!(File.open(file.path))
  end
end
```

This works as expected.

I can save a line of code like this:

```
@post.snippet.store!(
  File.open(
    File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "tmp", 'test.html'), 'w')
  )
)
```

But is this correct? I thought I can do something like this:

```
@post.snippet.store!(
  File.join(Rails.root, "tmp", 'test.html'), 'w'
) { |f| f << data})
```

But this throws an `IOError: closed stream`

Any suggestions how to improve that? Or is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should write your string to file:

```
...
file = File.open(yourfile, 'w') { |file| file.write(data) }

@post.snippet = File.open(path_to_file)
```

Comment: You shoul write your string to file.(file = File.open(yourfile, 'w') { |file| file.write(data) })
You should assigned this file to your snippet(@post.snippet = File.open(path_to_file))

Comment: everything seems to be available described .